# waiting for a synchronous funtion to finish

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

Let's say I have a function that returns a promise, `functionThatReturnsPromise` and I am using that function in a normal function, `normalFunction`.

```
normalFunction() {
    functionThatReturnsPromise().then(() => do something,);
}
```

I know I can wait for `functionThatReturnsPromise` inside `normalFunction` by using `functionThatReturnsPromise().then(...)` but what if I want `normalFunction` to finish when I am using my `normalFunction` elsewhere?

```
anotherNormalFunction() {
    normalFunction() // here i want this function to finish before proceeding 
                     // to the next line
}
```

I have tried `normalFunction().then(...)` and `await normalFunction()` but these don't seem to work. Is it possible?

Comment: synchronous functions do block the execution until finished (that's why they are called `synchronous`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`normalFunction` **will** finish before the next line is executed.

It's just the `normalFunction` does nothing except **trigger** an asynchronous function.

If you want to wait for the asynchronous function to finish before continuing, then you need to change `normalFunction` so that it returns a promise that doesn't resolve until that asynchronous function has resolved.

e.g. the promise returned by that asynchronous function.

```
normalFunction() {
    return functionThatReturnsPromise().then(() => do something,);
}
```